# Merge ignoring conflicting commits

Tags: git, merge

I have a local fork with big changes that I can't maintain and I want to synchronize it with a remote upstream branch. When I merge upstream into my fork, I would like the commits that conflict with my fork to be simply ignored. Do you know how to do this?

To summarize, I would like to:

- ignore any commits that conflict.
- Never overwrite local files.
- Have an up-to-date fork.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to discard or keep conflicting commits in your fork?

Comment: Only discard, but I would like to have the return of the not merged commits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping your fork up-to-dated to the upstream means, you basically need to connect your branch there by `git-merge`. But as you know, even if you want to discard certain commits, the history will be on your merged commit so you need some handling to "discard" such commits. I would suggest a revert before running the merge.

So, if you can manually spend effort to selectively pick commits to discard, you can locally revert them before running merge.

```
git checkout upstream/master
git revert bad-commit-yesterday # NOTE: the order of revert matters
git revert bad-commit-one-month-ago # commit-hash = e.g., abcde123
git checkout origin/master
git merge --log abcde123
```

Alternatively, if you want to do this very quick, here's the dirty method.

```
git checkout origin/master # your repo
git merge --log upstream/master # Conflict
git checkout origin/master - <file_path_1> ... # I assume you want to keep your "local" change in origin/master
```

Answer (score 0):

Git's `git merge` does not work commit-by-commit.  To skip commits that cause conflicts would require that you work commit-by-commit.  You would need to write your own software to do this.  *That part* would be relatively easy in all *linear* cases, but would rapidly bog down in complex cases (merging commit sequences that contain merges), and would have little value in most practical systems because skipping a commit that causes an *earlier* merge conflict will often result in *most or all subsequent commits having a merge conflict*.

In other words, given a commit stream like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H <-I ...
```

as you attempt to "cherry-merge"<sup>1</sup> commits one at a time, if you skip `G` because it has a conflict, you will find that `H` *depends on `G`* and therefore has a conflict, and `I` *depends on `H`* and therefore has a conflict, and so on.

The final result of this is that you merge up to some stasis point, and then stop acquiring most new commits.  So I would recommend not even attempting this.  You may have an oddball case where this doesn't really happen, though, and in that case, feel free to take a stab at writing "cherry-merge".

---

<sup>1</sup>This is my made-up name for the new Git command you need to write.  It's a combination of cherry-pick and merge, so I named it "cherry-merge", but that may be a terrible name in the end.  [Naming is one of the hard problems in computing, after all.](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/19836)

(I'm somewhat mis-using the "naming things" idea here, on purpose, but it applies.  I'm also alluding to the joke variants that add "off by one" errors to the "two hard things".)